# Power locks not working 2009 Honda Civic EX

Tags: honda, civic, audio

I recently changed the radio on my Honda Civic and after I installed it I realized my key wasn't locking the doors. I replaced the battery on the key and still nothing. I also noticed that the power locks only work when the car is turned on. When its off the power locks don't work at all.

I also tried reprogramming the key but i get nothing. And I also checked all fuses. They all work. And same problem with the lights. Usually when i would turn the car off the lights would come on until I locked the car but now they don't turn on when the car is shut off. I have to manually turn them on.

Comment: I suspect that either the wiring harness adapter used to connect the new headunit is incorrect or faulty - have you tried removing the new unit to see if the issues go away?

Comment: Yea i unplugged it and nothing.

Comment: Did you replace it with the stock one? Definitely sounds like something has got the car's CANBUS sulking. Has your car got IMID?